# How to avoid duplicating methods in angular services

Tags: javascript, angular, dry

Is there a way to avoid writing the same code in every service.

I've multiple services for different API endpoints:

```
  getLecturesData(orderBy?: string, orderDirection = 'asc', page = 1, pageSize = 10): Observable<LecturesData> {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.set('order_direction', orderDirection);
    params = params.set('page', page.toString());
    params = params.set('page_size', pageSize.toString());
    if (orderBy) { params = params.set('order_by', orderBy); }

    return this.http.get<LecturesData>('/api/lectures', {params});
  }
```

```
  getStudentsData(orderBy?: string, orderDirection = 'asc', page = 1, pageSize = 5): Observable<StudentsData> {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.set('order_direction', orderDirection);
    params = params.set('page', page.toString());
    params = params.set('page_size', pageSize.toString());
    if (orderBy) { params = params.set('order_by', orderBy); }

    return this.http.get<StudentsData>('/api/students', {params});
  }
```

As you can see, the code is nearly the same, except the `url` and the `type` of the return value.
Is it possible to place the duplicated part in a separat "thing"?

Comment: You have one service for each endpoint?These 2 methods above are on different services?

Comment: Exactly. Each method is part of a different service.

Answer (score 1):

I would create an interface for the arguments and create a private generic function to make the request.

```js
export interface QueryOptions {
  orderBy?: string;
  orderDirection: string;
  page: number;
  pageSize: number;
}
```

```js
getLecturesData(options: QueryOptions): Observable<LecturesData> {
  return this.getData<StudentsData>('/api/lectures', options);
}

getStudentsData(options: QueryOptions): Observable<StudentsData> {
    return this.getData<StudentsData>('/api/students', options);
}

private getData<T>(options: QueryOptions): Observable<T> {
  const params: HttpParams = this.getOptionsParams(options);
  return this.http.get<T>(url, {params});
}

private getOptionsParams(options: QueryOptions): HttpParams {
  let params = new HttpParams();
  params = params.set('order_direction', options.orderDirection || 'asc');
  params = params.set('page', (page || 1).toString());
  params = params.set('page_size', (pageSize || 10).toString());
  if (orderBy) { params = params.set('order_by', orderBy); }
  return params;
}
```